# Difference between Hibernate and Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I found a lot of similar questions

- [Difference between Hibernate library and Hibernate JPA library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426743/difference-between-hibernate-library-and-hibernate-jpa-library)
- [What's the difference between JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)
- [similarity and difference between jpa and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770211/similarity-and-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)

but no one answers my next question. What diference between classical hibernate approach using `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` and JPA `javax.persistence.EntityManager` implementation? I heard, that this JPA implementation uses `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` and works like wrapper, is it real?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Indeed.

JPA is simply an API that allows you to abstract from the used persistence layer. Hibernate provides an implementation of the `EntityManager` interface that acts as an `adapter` - it uses the same underlying methods as a hibernate `SessionManager`.

The idea is that you could, for example, switch your implementation to Eclipse Link and not have to change any of your source code.

Answer (score 5):

JPA is just a specification, meaning there is no implementation. You can annotate your classes as much as you would like with JPA annotations, however without an implementation nothing will happen. Think of JPA as the guidelines that must be followed or an interface, while Hibernate's JPA implementation is code that meets the API as defined by the JPA specification and provides the under the hood functionality.

When you use Hibernate with JPA you are actually using the **Hibernate JPA implementation**. The benefit of this is that you can swap out Hibernate's implementation of JPA for another implementation of the JPA specification. When you use straight **Hibernate you are locking into the implementation** because other ORMs may use different methods/configurations and annotations, therefore you cannot just switch over to another ORM.

Comment: you have explained it really well. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer of you question

> What diference between classical hibernate approach using
>   org.hibernate.SessionFactory and JPA javax.persistence.EntityManager
>   implementation?

```
org.hibernate.SessionFactory
```

if you change the undeline ORM to IBatis(for e.g) you need to change the code as well.

```
javax.persistence.EntityManager
```

if you change the undeline ORM to IBatis(for e.g) you dont need to change the code.

Comment: I have answered your first ques.

Answer (score 2):

To your First question,

JPA is a Java API specification which describes the management of relational data in applications using Java Platform. where as Hibernate is a ORM (Object Relational Mapping) library which follows JPA specification.

You can think JPA as a set of Rules which is implemented by Hibernate.

And answer for your second question,

As JPA is just an abstracted persistence layer it requires implementation. and Hibernate implements EntityManager interface that uses hibernate SessionManager.

In this way, you are completely detached from the implementation way, means you can switch to any of Hibernate or OenJPA or any other whenever you want, no additional code changes required.

Answer (score 0):

| Keyword | JPA | Hibernate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Location | Described in `javax.persistence` package | Described in `org.hibernate` |
| Intent | It's only Java speicification | It's is an implementation of JPA. |
| Functionality | It describes the handling of relational data in Java applications | Hibernate is an Obejct relational mapping (ORM) tool that is used to save the Java objects in the relational database system |
| Standard API | It's a standard API that permits to perform database operations | It is used in mapping Java data types with SQL data types and database tables |
| CRUD action | To perform CRUD actions for instances of mapped entity classes, it uses `EntityManager` interface which is supplied by `EntityManagerFactory` | To perform CRUD actions for instances of mapped entity classes, it uses `Session` interface which is supplied by `SessionFactory` |