# hibernate entity-manager v/s hibernate jpa package which to use

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

How do I configure hibernate?

If hibernate-entitymanager package is used for JPA then what good is of hibernate-jpa package. And I have seen that they use `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` class is used for JPA provider in persistence.xml which is in hibernate-entitymanager package.

In some cases, I have not seen the provider tag in `persistence.xml`. In this case which class is used?. Does `Session` class has `EntityManager` or implements it . And none of hibernate beans are specified in Spring-application context file directly. Instead `spring.orm` packages are used. So spring framework picks which class for JPA functionality.

`org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean` picks which bean if provider tag is specified and if provider tag is not specified which bean is picked?

Comment: Picking which software to use is not on topic at programmers.stackexchange.com...

Comment: @AndritchiAlexei see above ^^^. Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate JPA is a standard JPA implementation. See also these other questions about differences.

- [What's the difference between JPA and Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)
- [Difference between Hibernate and Hibernate JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002481/difference-between-hibernate-and-hibernate-jpa)
- [similarity and difference between jpa and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770211/similarity-and-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)

Session and EntityManager do approximately the same thing. EntityManager is the "new way."

I'm not clear on what your questions are about the persistence.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for reply but my Question was in which package the jpa implementation actually is . Is it in hibernate entitymanager.jar or hibernate-jpa2.1.jar .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply but my Question was in which package the jpa implementation actually is . Is it in hibernate entitymanager.jar or hibernate-jpa2.1.jar . I found this fallowing link to be of little use
 .https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch01s02s01.html

but in this case in persistence.xml file contains org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence as jpa provider but this class is in hibernate-entitymanager package . But they also told that hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar is the JAR containing the JPA 2.0 API, it provides all the interfaces and concrete classes that the specification defines as public API. Said otherwise, you can use this JAR to bootstrap any JPA provider implementation. in this fallowing link 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html please could some one help me with this